# How to update my template in my nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-ui

im using tailwind css to build my nextjs app, so im copying this template from tailwind ui and it says for it to work properly i have to..

````
 {/*
      This example requires updating your template:

      ```
      <html class="h-full">
      <body class="h-full">
      ```
    */}
````

and im not sure where is what i have to update that.
this is what my tailwind.config.js looks like,

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

if you guys can give me a hand i would appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Your template needs your html and body tag to have the `h-full` class.

The way to do this with Next.JS is to create a custom document. To do so, create a new file in your pages folder: `./pages/_document.{jsx,tsx}` and add the following snippet:

```
import Document, {Html, Head, Main, NextScript} from 'next/document';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return {...initialProps};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html className="h-full"> // This is where you add the class to the html tag of your page
        <Head/>
        <body className="h-full"> // This is where you add the class to the body tag of your page
        <Main/>
        <NextScript/>
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

More information about custom document in the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).

Comment: thanks for the response, but after creating that file inside pages and copying your code still the template doesnt properly work. should i put something else besides className="h-full" next to html and body? i want the template to work on a specific file inside components.

Comment: (1) Did you restart your dev server ? (2) Does the new class appear correctly when inspecting your dom ? Otherwise I will need more context to help, do you have a link to the source? or at least a link to the template your are using?

Comment: i did restart it. and it appears like how its supposed to in the DOM when i check the elements in my devtool. im thinking this has to do with my _app.js and the layouts i use for every page...im thinking for this specific page i dont need any layout, just the content of the template and thats it

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything I could think of adding this to my tailwind.css did it for me.

```
@layer base {
    html,
    body,
    body>div:first-child,
    div#__next,
    div#__next>div {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```